# Windows 2008R2 move machine off of Clustered Shared Volume

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2

We currently have a Windows 2008 R2 Hyper-V cluster using Clusterd Shared Volumes with highly available VM's. Is it possible to move these machines to another Hyper-V server with normal direct attached storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are several ways to do that, though not live, while they're running.

If you are using System Center Virtual Machine Manager, you can tell it to move the VMs using "Quick Migration."

If you're doing it yourself, shut the machines down, copy the VHD files, "export" the VM settings, "import" them on the other machine.  And point the storage devices at the VHDs files in the new location.